# How can I prevent constant requests when adding, deleting, and listing data in React using useCallback and useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am adding, deleting and listing my data. I want these transactions to be seen on the screen after the transaction, but I don't want it to send requests all the time. I did the following operation, but it still sends requests constantly. How can I do that?

```
const fetchParts = useCallback(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8090/parts/all")
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("API call error:", err.message);
      });
  }, [data]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchParts();
  }, [fetchParts]);
```

I don't want it to send request when I'm not taking action

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `useCallback` hook in a wrong way.

Check the **dependency array** of you `fetchParts`'s useCallback hook, you put `data` inside dependency array, so every time `data` changes, your `fetchParts`'s reference is changed, but since you use `setData` inside your `fetchParts` method, you are creating an infinite loop!

So, first of all, remove `data` from `fetchPart`'s dependency array:

```js
const fetchParts = useCallback(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8090/parts/all")
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("API call error:", err.message);
      });
  }, []); // <-- no `data` into dependency array

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchParts();
  }, [fetchParts]);
```

Last, if you want something to happen when data changes, add another `useEffect` hook which depends on `data` changes:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    // do something every time `data` changes 
  }, [data]); // <-- executes when `data` changes
```

Documentation:

- https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback
- https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect

Comment: I changed my codes like this but I couldn't get rid of the constant requests to my api.

Comment: @ErkanTufan can you please provide full component's code?